# Can the interchange categorization on a card be detected prior to charging it in authorize.net?

Tags: api, authorize.net

I'm looking at the possibility of setting up limited acceptance of debit cards online.  However, as I research, I see that there are huge differences in the interchange rate between debit cards that are regulated under the recent Durbin amendment and those that are exempt.  Depending on my merchant account fee structure, this could give us wildly different costs based on how the transaction gets categorized.

If I'm using authorize.net as the gateway, is it possible to use their API to determine the categorization of the card on the interchange with just an authorize transaction? (and thus accept only cards that I know can be processed cheaply, and give an "i'm sorry" message to everyone else).  Is there any other way to identify them without actually making the charge on the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. The rates used to process a transaction are determined at transaction time and are not available via any API. You can only find out what rate was charged by viewing the reporting offered by the merchant account provider.